# зависает форма с отдельным потоком Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2, qthread

Пишу ПО которое будет подключатся к удаленному компьютеру и получить доступ ко всем данным удаленного компьютера по определённому пути.
На данный момент есть проблема что логика которая подключается к удаленному компьютеру не работает если нажимать на IP который не в сети и ложит форму с тем условием, что подключение написано в отдельном потоке. Для подключения использую библиотеку win32api и win32net.
Сама форма написана на PyQt5.
Также пробовал делать отключение win32net.NetUseDel(fr'\{ip}', username, win32net.USE_FORCE) после того как подключаешь на другой IP - не помогает.
Нужна помощь в решении проблемы.
Заранее спасибо!

КОД:

```
class ThreadListSelect(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, items=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.items = items
    def run(self):
        for i in self.items:
            ip = str(i.text()).split()[-1]
            username = 'admin'
            password = '123'
            use_dict = {}
            path = use_dict['remote'] = unicode(fr'\\{ip}\\C$\\Users\\admin\\Desktop')
            use_dict['password'] = unicode(password)
            use_dict['username'] = unicode(username)
            win32net.NetUseAdd(None, 3, use_dict)
            # self.Explorer_PC_A(path)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.listWidget_PC_A_B.clicked.connect(self.ItemClick)

    def ItemClick(self):
        self.thread = ThreadListSelect(items=self.ui.listWidget_PC_A_B.selectedItems())
        self.thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1) Для этого поток не нужен - все действия с сетью являются асинхронными. 2) Зачем использовать winapi, если в Qt есть собственный модуль работы с сетью и причем он кроссплатформенный?!

Comment: @AlexanderChernin подскажи пж какой метод в Qt есть для работы с сетью, а конкретно можно ли через него получить доступ к папке другого ПК?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-programming.html